# Set message into file download blank page returned from web service

Tags: java, rest, servlets, download

I have this web service for file download from email (I provide URL for download):

```
@Override
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
@RequestMapping(value = { "download"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void downloadFile(HttpServletResponse response, @RequestParam(value="filePath", required = true) String filePath) {
    try{
        File file = new File(filePath);
        if (file.isFile()){
            try(InputStream is = new FileInputStream(file.getAbsolutePath())){
                setResponse(response, is, file, "attachment; filename=");
            }catch (Exception e1){
                ErrorResponse errorResponse= ErrorResponseBuilder.buildErrorResponse(e1);
                LOG.error("Threw exception in FleetAndCarControllerImpl::downloadStatisticalFile :" + errorResponse.getStacktrace());
            }
        }else{
            //TODO write that file is not present
        }
    }catch (Exception e) {
        ErrorResponse errorResponse= ErrorResponseBuilder.buildErrorResponse(e);
        LOG.error("Threw exception in FleetAndCarControllerImpl::downloadStatisticalFile :" + errorResponse.getStacktrace());
    }
}
```

and setResponse method:

```
private void setResponse(HttpServletResponse response, InputStream is, File file, String useOfFile) throws Exception{
        response.setHeader("Expires", "0");
        response.setHeader("Cache-Control","must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        response.setContentType(Files.probeContentType(file.toPath()));
        response.setHeader("Content-Description"," File Transfer");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", useOfFile + file.getName());
        response.setHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding"," binary");
        long size = Utils.stream(is, response.getOutputStream());
        response.addHeader("Content-Length", Long.toString(size));
        response.flushBuffer();
    }
```

It works fine when file exists, now I would like to write a message if file doesn't exist because now the user views a blank white page and it doesn't know what is happening.
Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND, "File was not found");
```

Or better send a redirect to a page with an error message/explanations on what to do next.

Comment: I've tried and it works. Thanks. For the redirect I should use response.sendRedirect right?

Comment: right, see the javadocs for the HttpServletResponse: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html